# Javascript string comparison using toString() does unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, immutable.js

I'm trying to write a code that overrides 'isEmpty' of Immutable.Record

Anyway, I have a problem about string comparison.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'

export default function createSchema(schema) {
  const record = Immutable.Record(schema)

  const Schema = class extends record {
    isEmpty() {
      const aString = this.toString()
      const bString = this.constructor().toString()
      console.log('comp1', this.toString() === this.constructor().toString())
      console.log('comp2', aString === bString)
    }
  }

  return Schema
}
```

In following codes,

```
import createSchema from 'there'

const aRecord = createSchema({ id: '' })
const a = new aRecord({ id: '1' })
a.isEmpty()
```

I think both 'comp1' and 'comp2' should print false. (a is not empty!)

But only 'comp1' gets true and 'comp2' gets false.

What's wrong?

======== added =======

Thanks to @Felix Kling, I tried 'new' keyword

I found very illogical thing that changing one line

```
const bString = new this.constructor().toString()
```

makes comp1 false.

But,

```
console.log('comp1', this.toString() === new this.constructor().toString())
```

does not makes comp1 false

Comment: A general observation: You probably want to do `new this.constructor()`.

Comment: I must be blind ... how is the code related to `a = new A` - I don't see where `A` is defined, so ...

Comment: Oh WOW ... the question just changed completely didn't it!!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX  It was typo... A was aRecord

Comment: @Luan - the question changed significantly for a while :p

Comment: @FelixKling unfortunately, new didn't solve the problem well.. I appended your opinion